# jq: replache slash by dash chracter

Tags: jq

I need to replace slash character by `"-"`.

I mean:

```json
[
  "1934/08/20",
  "1961/01/10",
  "1952/01/25",
  "1967/07/24"
]
```

I need:

```json
[
  "1934-0820",
  "1961-01-10",
  "1952-01-25",
  "1967-07-24"
]
```

Is there anyway to get it?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strptime` to parse the dates, then `strftime` to format them. `map` can map that filter over your entire list.

```
$ cat tmp.json
[
  "1934/08/20",
  "1961/01/10",
  "1952/01/25",
  "1967/07/24"
]
$ jq 'map(strptime("%Y/%m/%d") | strftime("%F"))' tmp.json
[
  "1934-08-20",
  "1961-01-10",
  "1952-01-25",
  "1967-07-24"
]
```

(`%F` is a shortcut, where available, for `%Y-%m-%d`.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to replace all the `/` with `-`'s, [`gsub`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#gsub(regex;string),gsub(regex;string;flags)) is the way to go:

```
jq 'map(gsub("\/"; "-"))'
```

Will produce

```json
[
  "1934-08-20",
  "1961-01-10",
  "1952-01-25",
  "1967-07-24"
]
```

As you can test in [this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4wwrBRMljn)